# Technical Term for "side by side scene editing"?

Tags: editing

I am looking for video editing software that has a feature, but I don't know the name of it. It was a feature I had in EditDV around 2000, but I have not found it since.

Essentially, setting the END FRAME of one scene while "simultaneously" setting the START FRAME of the NEXT scene. You had side-by-side, frame-by-frame control over the end and start points of 2 different scenes, at the same time. There was also a 5-second preview button that showed you just the video around your edit, which was really nice.

Does anyone know what this is called? And more to the point, a reasonable ($50~) video editing software package (for windows) that has this?

Comment: What was the behavior of the system when you were adjusting?  Are you talking about where you can move the point of the cut without moving either video clip?  ie, the first clip gets one frame shorter at the end and the second clip gets one frame longer at the beginning?

Comment: No, adjusting one scene's length would not affect the other scene's length. Removing frames from one side (or both sides) would result in a shorter movie. I mean, I can "duplicate" the behavior in most softwares by clicking "cut" or "break", then deleting that tiny bit, then previewing ... but if I'm wrong I have to undo (or trim a little more, delete, etc).

Comment: Sounds like classic [3 point editing](https://documentation.apple.com/en/finalcutpro/usermanual/index.html#chapter=36%26section=1%26tasks=true).

Answer (score 4):

What you are describing is called a "ripple edit" (because the adjustment you make to the clip ripples through the rest of the timeline that comes after it).  It may also be called something like "ripple trim" as a more specific term for the precise type of ripple edit.  It is a feature available in any decent professional editing package.  Depending on your other needs, it's probably worth taking a look at DaVinci Resolve as Resolve is a high end professional product which also offers a completely free version with about 90-95% of its features included.  It's out of your price range for the full version (at $299 for a license that they haven't charged for an upgrade in the last 3-4 versions) but there is a decent possibility it will cover your needs in the free version.

There is lots of other software with Ripple Edit capabilities, but Resolve is the cheapest one I personally work with enough to be able to recommend.  I've been out of the consumer market for a very long time, so I'm not sure what products would be current there.

Comment: Thanks. I just did a little research on "ripple edit". It looks like it's just a way to slide the start/end of a clip, without actually "trimming" it (so it's still there if you want to adjust later). It turns out my cheapy software DOES have this feature, which is great. This technically answers the question "what's it called" (so I'll mark it!), I guess I was also hoping for a more refined "ripple edit editor" type of tool. I will check out davinci. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, there's no "mark as answer" here that I can see, but, this is the answer!

Comment: @emery.noel - It looks like you got disassociated from your user somehow as this comment was under a different user than the original post.  You can request a user merge from the Contact Us page on the footer.

Comment: @emery.noel - also, the edit you described as sliding the start/end of a clip without actually trimming it is called a slip edit because you are slipping the clip within it's spot in the timeline.  Ripple has to be causing a change in length of the overall timeline for either the content added or the content removed.

Comment: thanks, I'll make the request, I posted as anonymous but later synced with my other stackexchange accounts. As for the slip edits, when I drag the edge of the clip, it DOES change the overall length of the whole project. In dragging the "edge" of the clip, I'm changing its in _or_ out point, not both (and I'm not changing the adjacent clips), and I'm not moving the clip in relation to other clips. Would that be a "slip ripple" edit?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62364/discussion-on-answer-by-aj-henderson-technical-term-for-side-by-side-scene-edit).